# How to speed up my prediction task

Tags: numpy

I'm currently working on an implementation of [U-net](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) in keras based on : [Lung Segmentation](https://github.com/imlab-uiip/lung-segmentation-2d)

I'm working on very large images (~20000*~20000) and to get a probability map for my whole image I use 256*256 patches.

At the moment I'm doing as follows :

```
UNet = load_model(model_name)

for posX in range(0,im.level_dimensions[level][0]-256,stride):
    for posY in range(0,im.level_dimensions[level][1]-256,stride):

        xx = np.expand_dims(imload[posY:posY+256,posX:posX+256,:],0)
        yy = maskload[posY:posY+256,posX:posX+256,:]

        #The following line is the bottleneck
        pred = UNet.predict(xx)[..., 0].reshape(patchShape[:2])

        #Reconstruct the probability map
        part=outputProba[posY:posY+256,posX:posX+256]
        part[:,:]+=pred[0:part.shape[0],0:part.shape[1]]
        outputProbaTimes[posY:posY+256,posX:posX+256]+=1
```

This piece of code takes about 1 min to execute, with the stride set to 256. I would it to run with stride 64, but it takes ~16 min.

I'm pretty new to keras and Deep Learning, and I would like to know if anyone would have smart tips to speed up this code.

I looked around to use predict_generator, It would be great because it can take advantage of multiprocessing. But I'm not understanding the point of generating data when predicting.

Thanks for your help !

ps: The code is running on nvidia GTX 1080

ps2: the UNet.predict is the predict from [keras](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

Comment: It would be nice to know what `UNet.predict` is

Comment: You're right forgot to specify. It is the predict function from keras ,